# Unable to determine type in mono-runtime when NSArray is passed to the xamarin layer from native ios layer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono

We have an NSDictionary containing an NSArray being passed to the Xamarin layer from the native ios code. But as NSArray is weakly typed, converting it into a strongly typed data (to add to json structure) is proving to be a problem as type-casting to a particular data-type is not possible. 
For example, the NSArray might contain an integer, a dictionary and a string and hence I am unable to determine a type in such a case.

Is there a way out to creating a proper valid json with strongly types data types in such a scenario? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is it work if you determine a type of  `object` in your case?Such as `List<object> list = new List<object>();`.

Comment: @jackHua The type has to be well defined to convert to json values. Object would become a generic type and hence cannot be converted to json directly.